# Crystal Report sub report grow issue

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using crystal 10.2, with VS2005 .net. I have used sub report in section and given can grow true in reports. When it displays in browser it shows text vertically grows in columns, where i wanted it to grow horizontally, even if there is so much space it does not grow horizontally.
Please help me how i can do formatting horizontally.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try extending your sub-report's width as said by Mr.HichemC, and you can change the page orientation to landscape if you need even more width.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the field's width to fit the page's max width, then set Text Wrap option for multilines.

Comment: I have already checked "can grow" option. There is no Text Wrap property.It gives "can grow" and maximum no. of lines(0 for no limit).